# R select value from column index

Tags: arrays, r

I have two sets of columns in a `data.frame`: the time at a location, and the attributes of that location.

```
> FRAME <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(5, 0,1), rnorm(5, 0,1), rchisq(5, 1,4), rchisq(5,1,4)))
> names(FRAME) <- c("Var1", "Var2", "Time1", "Time2")
> FRAME$LONGEST <- apply(FRAME[,3:4], 1, function(x) which.max(x))
> FRAME
        Var1       Var2    Time1     Time2 
1  0.2919722 -0.1069673 4.666482  1.556280 
2 -0.6518142  1.1226106 4.867360  9.251785 
3 -1.8612779  0.2874144 7.578548  1.820536 
4 -0.7059450 -0.1036744 1.428684 16.937638 
5  2.1793696  0.8993723 1.639895  7.942257
```

I would like to select as a new variable whichever `Var*` has the longest `Time*` associated with it. Identifying which column is easy enough,

```
> FRAME
        Var1       Var2    Time1     Time2 LONGEST
1  0.2919722 -0.1069673 4.666482  1.556280       1
2 -0.6518142  1.1226106 4.867360  9.251785       2
3 -1.8612779  0.2874144 7.578548  1.820536       1
4 -0.7059450 -0.1036744 1.428684 16.937638       2
5  2.1793696  0.8993723 1.639895  7.942257       2
```

The most straightforward way to me to retrieve the correct column gives a totally useless result

```
FRAME[,FRAME$LONGEST]
        Var1       Var2     Var1.1     Var2.1     Var2.2
1  0.2919722 -0.1069673  0.2919722 -0.1069673 -0.1069673
2 -0.6518142  1.1226106 -0.6518142  1.1226106  1.1226106
3 -1.8612779  0.2874144 -1.8612779  0.2874144  0.2874144
4 -0.7059450 -0.1036744 -0.7059450 -0.1036744 -0.1036744
5  2.1793696  0.8993723  2.1793696  0.8993723  0.8993723
```

What am I missing? Is there a way to change `which.max()` to select from a different matrix than its reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just:

```
apply(FRAME,1,function(x) x[1:2][which.max(x[3:4])])
```

Comment: Brilliant. I thought I had tried all combinations of `which.max` and `apply`. Forgot that `[]` can be stacked as well as nested.